# fSelect() Clear Selection jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, fselect

In this post [fSelect Clear Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262677/fselect-clear-selection/53635735#comment91843125_52263013)

Show to how implement clear all selection en fselect() jquery plugin.

Thanks, this worked for me, but I have a problem. I have two fSelect multi-select drop-down on my page with different data.

When I execute this action " $('.fs-label').html('Select some options'); " is updating the two label.

How do I solve this? Thanks.